# MATLAB parallel toolbox, remoteParallelFunction : RUNTIME_ERROR during function evaluation

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm using the parallel computing toolbox (PCT) in combination with the Simbiology toolbox in MATLAB 2012b.  I’m receiving an intermittent error message when I run my script with a remote pool of workers, but not with a local pool of workers:

Caught `std::exception` Exception message is:

```
vector::_M_range_check

Error using parallel_function (line 589)
Error in remote execution of remoteParallelFunction : RUNTIME_ERROR

Error in PSOFit (line 486)
                        parfor ns = 1:r.NumSwp

Error in PSOopt_driver (line 209)
        PSOFit(ObjFuncName,LB,UB,PSOopts);
```

The error does not occur when I comment out the call to the function sbiosimulate (a SimBiology function for model evaluation).

I have a couple of ideas:

- I’ve introduced some sort of race condition, that causes a problem in accessing the model variables (is this possible in MATLAB?)
- Model compilation in simbiology is sometimes but not always compatible with the PCT, and I’ve hit some sort of edge case
- Since sbiosimulate evaluates compiled C++ code, for some inputs there might be a bug in the source that generates the exception

I am aware of [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-6BT0PX/?solution=1-6BT0PX).

Comment: Could you be running out of memory on a remote machine?

Comment: Are all other variables truly equal when you run it locally, ie are you using the same data set? running the same number of iterations? etc...?

Comment: Are you certain that all workers are running the current version of matlab?

Comment: Do all of the workers have the most up to date version of the code?

Comment: @slayton : The enviroments for running the script (dataset, optimization setting, etc.) are equal for local and remote workers. All workers are updated regularly with the latest version of the code and they are running the same version of Matlab. It would be worth to check the memory on a remote machine. Still, is there any other possibility that could explain the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer of SimBiology. I believe this is a bug that was introduced into SimBiology's C++ code in the R2012a release. The bug is triggered when a simulation ends without producing any simulation results. This can sometimes occur when the model is configured to report only particular times (using the OutputTimes options) AND the simulation is configured to end after a particular amount of real time (using the MaximumWallClock option). Basically, the simulation "times out" before it ever gets a chance to log the first output time.

One way to work around this problem is to always include time 0 in the OutputTimes. This time will always get logged before evaluating the MaximumWallClock criterion, preventing the bug from getting triggered. I am also contacting this user directly and will work on fixing the bug in a future release.